# XMLHttpRequest is not a function

Tags: javascript, xmlhttprequest

I'm trying to write some client-side JavaScript using `XMLHttpRequest`:

```
$('#someId').on('input', function() {
  var req = XMLHttpRequest();
  // …
});
```

but I get the following error:

> XMLHttpRequest is not a function. (In 'XMLHttpRequest()', 'XMLHttpRequest' is an instance of XMLHttpRequestConstructor)

How to fix this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

missed `new`, must be:

```
$('#someId').on('input', function() {
  var req = new XMLHttpRequest();
  // …
});
```

you can read more about XHRHttpRequest here -
https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/XMLHttpRequest

and how to work with it here -
https://developer.mozilla.org/ru/docs/XMLHttpRequest
(only this page translation exists yet, but google translate can help a lot :) )

p.s. If you are using jQuery - better to use `$.ajax()` as @synthet1c said.

Read more about it here - http://api.jquery.com/jquery.ajax/

Comment: You should probably also just use the jQuery $.ajax method if jQuery is already installed as it will give you a consistent api across all browsers (ie)

Answer (score 1):

If you are already using jQuery, you can make ajax requests with `$.ajax()` method:

Example:

```
$('#someId').on('input', function() {

    $.ajax({

        url: 'some_file.php',
        data: {

            postparam_1: 'ok',
            postparam_2: 'no'
        },
        method: 'get',
        success: function(x) {

            alert(x); // string result from server
        },
        error: function() {

            alert('Error!');
        }
    });
});
```

If you want to use It in your app you have to retrieve XmlHttpRequest object that works across all browsers.

```
var XMLHttpFactories = [
    function () {return new XMLHttpRequest()},
    function () {return new ActiveXObject("Msxml2.XMLHTTP")},
    function () {return new ActiveXObject("Msxml3.XMLHTTP")},
    function () {return new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP")}
];

function createXMLHTTPObject() {
    var xmlhttp = false;
    for (var i=0;i<XMLHttpFactories.length;i++) {
        try {
            xmlhttp = XMLHttpFactories[i]();
        }
        catch (e) {
            continue;
        }
        break;
    }
    return xmlhttp;
}
```

Comment: only read the second part if you want to support IE6 https://developer.microsoft.com/en-us/microsoft-edge/ie6countdown/

Answer (score 1):

`XMLHttpRequest` is a constructor and not a (usual) function in JavaScript and you need to use `new XMLHttpRequest()`

```
$('#someId').on('input', function() {
  var req = new XMLHttpRequest();
  // …
});
```

Refer this MDN article on using `XMLHttpRequest`: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/XMLHttpRequest/Using_XMLHttpRequest